# Only 1 Table of Contents entry for multiple bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, bibliographies

I have split my Bibliography into written and online sources. However, I have now two titles that are in my ToC. I would like to have only one title "Bibliography" and two section (smaller) titles (not in ToC) named "Written Sources" and "Online Sources".

My setup:

```
%BIBLIOGRAPHY
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

```
% WRITTEN SOURCES
\begingroup
\linespread{1.3}    
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,nottype=misc]
\endgroup

% ONLINE SOURCES
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Online Resources} %Title
\begingroup
\linespread{1.3}    
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,type=misc]
\endgroup
```

The end result should look something like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: don't use `bibintoc` if you don't want it in the toc, use `subbibliography`. And use \printbibheading{heading=bibintoc,title=Bibliography} for the main title.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. It worked great. The brackets for the \printbibheading should however be square brackets: \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title=Bibliography]

Comment: yes, sorry, you are right.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here?

Comment: @moewe done, could you ping me in the chat for a short question?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the heading type  `bibintoc` if you don't want it *in the toc*, use `subbibliography` instead.

For the main title you can use

```
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title=Bibliography]
```